# How to configure Apache WSGI for Python to serve only non-existing files?

Tags: apache-2.2, python, django, wsgi

I would like to setup Django with WSGI and Apache on root (/) of the website, but I would like that Apache servers through WSGI (and Django) only those URLs which do not have corresponding file to serve directly.

For PHP I would do something like this with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

and then rewrite to some index.php or something. But how to do that with WSGI?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the mod_wsgi documentation:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive

Don't use WSGIScriptAlias. Use AddHandler instead and use similar mod_rewrite tricks. A small fixup is required as a WSGI middleware in your WSGI script.